# Quotient of $R[x,x^{-1}]$ as $R[x]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I would like to understand a certain ring, which arises in many examples of calculations of Heegaard Floer homologies. If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity (in most cases, $\mathbb{Z}$ or a field), consider the $R[x]$-module of Laurent polynomials $R[x,x^{-1}]$. How can the quotient module $R[x,x^{-1}]/R[x]$ be described?

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear and simple

Comment: my pleasure, happy it helped! :) since this is sufficient for your purposes I have added my comments as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that every element of $R[x,x^{-1}]$ can be written uniquely in the form $a_nx^{-n}+\dots+a_1x^{-1}+b$, where $b\in R[x]$ and all $a_i\in R$, so every element of $R[x,x^{-1}]/R[x]$ has a unique representative of form $a_nx^{-n}+\dots+a_1x^{-1}$. In particular, $R[x,x^{-1}]/R[x]$ is isomorphic to the following module. The underlying set is $R[t]$, and the action of $R[x]$ on $R[t]$ is obtained by taking $R$ to act in the usual way and taking $x$ to act by $x\cdot at^n=at^{n-1}$ if $n>0$ and $x\cdot a=0$, for all $a\in R$.